# migrate js chart in angular with Echart

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts, angular-chart

i need to draw a graph chart i have this code referement in .js

```
   loadServizi(servizi => {
    loadConcetti(concetti => {
        graph = buildGraph(servizi, concetti);
        buildChartConcetti(graph);
    });
});
```

in angular i have replicate loadServizi , and  loadConcetti that return Observable<Concetti[]>  and the same for loadServizi  ,  function buildGraph need this 2 array of Object to drow graph , this is my implementation in angular:

```
 drowChartAngular(): void {
this.concettoService.getConcetti().subscribe(dataConcetti => {
  this.concettoService.getServizi().subscribe(dataservice=>{
    this.concetti = dataConcetti;
    this.servizi = dataservice;
    this.graph =  this.buildGraph(dataservice, dataConcetti);
  });
});
```

and in buildGraph function :

```
servizi.forEach(d => {
  let idServizio = `${this.DATA_CATEGORY.servizio.id}-${d.id}`;
  nodes[idServizio] = {
    id: idServizio,
    name: d.nome,
    category: this.DATA_CATEGORY.servizio.id,
    info: this.createServizioInfo(d),
    adjNodes: d.dominiInteresse.map(x => `${this.DATA_CATEGORY.concetto.id}-${x.concettoRelativo.id}`)
  };
});
```

at this line "adjNodes: d.dominiInteresse.map(x => `${this.DATA_CATEGORY.concetto.id}-${x.concettoRelativo.id}`)"  i have this error in console :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at DemoComponent.push../src/app/components/demo/demo.component.ts.DemoComponent.createServizioInfo (demo.component.ts:225:71)
at demo.component.ts:110:20
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at DemoComponent.push../src/app/components/demo/demo.component.ts.DemoComponent.buildGraph (demo.component.ts:104:13)
at SafeSubscriber._next (demo.component.ts:67:28)
at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196:1)
at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134:1)
at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77:1)
at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54:1)
at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77:
```

I don't know what can cause it if the map, or the double subscribe

Comment: in your data response "d.dominiInteresse" is undefined which is causing the issue. try this
d.dominiInteresse?.map

Comment: if i use ?.map is sintax error